# Android Permissions Issue

Tags: android, audio, permissions

I am writing a simple activity to record and save audio, preferably to a folder within my application, but, for simplicity, to the SD card. The line of code that's giving me trouble is

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "tempAppFiles/";
String filename = "test"+".mp4";
recorder.setOutputFile(path + filename);
```

where recorder is an instance of MediaRecorder.

When I run the application, I get a permissions error that states

```
07-31 15:51:51.810: W/System.err(13670): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/tempAppFiles/test.mp4 (Permission denied)
```

I looked this problem up and found that I needed to add several permission tags to my manifest, and I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

to my manifest.

I am still getting the same permissions issue, and I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you programmatically created the directory if its not there?

Comment: What does path.canWrite() say? did you put your permissions in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... The permissions seem to be correct, perhaps you've put them in the wrong place, they need to be [children of the root note .](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Next you c[an check, whether you can write](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) the file by checking

```
boolean canIWrite = path.canWrite();
```

As you also get a FileNotFound exception you could try...

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

...instead of...

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

If that is no help at all, there is still an official example of capturing audio - you should compare your code to:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Answer (score 0):

tempAppFiles does not set well with me. Seems like you should be writing to a directory that is under the package name of the app you are writing ...